# Mongo aggegation without an array in result

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, lookup

I am running such an aggregation on my collection:

```
db.getCollection('thoughts').aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      localField: "author_id",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "author"
    }
  }
])
```

The result is:

```
{
  /* my thought's body */
  "author" : [
    { /* my author's body */ }
  ]
}
```

Is there any possibility of getting result the same but without an array in the "author" field - just same object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
db.getCollection('thoughts').aggregate([
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "users",
          localField: "author_id",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "author"
        }
      },
      {"$unwind": "$author"}
    ])
```

$unwind deconstructs an array field from the input documents to output a document for each element.